# How to write arabic in github README file?

Tags: github, right-to-left

I need to write arabic (rtl) language in README.md file in github.
So how could I do this?

Answer (score 8):

You can't do this with markdown but you can surely do this with HTML.

```
<div dir="rtl">

## عنوان

### قائمة

<ul>
  <li>١. البند 1</li>
  <li>٢.البند 2</li>
  <li>٣.البند 3</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

If just some parts of the document need to be right-to-left:

```
## <div dir="rtl">عنوان</div>

### <div dir="rtl">قائمة</div>
<div dir="rtl"><ul>
  <li>١. البند 1</li>
  <li>٢.البند 2</li>
  <li>٣.البند 3</li>
</ul></div>
```

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi, I agree. You'll have to use HTML for the whole document then. Here's an example https://github.com/Roshanjossey/first-contributions/blob/master/translations/README.ar.md
GitHub Readme takes HTML too

Answer (score 6):

You could consider using [ahmadajmi/markdown-arabic](https://github.com/ahmadajmi/markdown-arabic) which includes a right-to-left markdown editor.

Online version is also available at [arabicmarkdown.netlify.com](https://arabicmarkdown.netlify.com/)

Comment: This lets you edit RTL texts, but when you put them in GitHub, they are still shown LTR...